# UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex not called when text field is in

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview

When I have the following code the clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method is called:

```
UIAlertView * alertTextField = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post To Facebook" message:@"What would you like the post to say?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
        alertTextField.tag = 2;
        [alertTextField show];
```

But when i add in the UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput in the delegate method is not called.

```
 UIAlertView * alertTextField = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post To Facebook" message:@"What would you like the post to say?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
        [alertTextField setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
        alertTextField.tag = 2;
        [alertTextField show];
```

Why is this?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you trying to support? Have you considered `UIAlertController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure that you added `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your view controller and your forget to add `alertTextField.delegate = self;` Then implement the delegate to receive the event.

```
UIAlertView * alertTextField = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post To Facebook" message:@"What would you like the post to say?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alertTextField setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
alertTextField.delegate = self; // you forget to add this line 
alertTextField.tag = 2;
[alertTextField show];


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
      NSString *test = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    }
 }
```

> UIAlertView no longer available/support in iOS 8 and above so in this place use UIAlertViewController, example for how to use UIAlertViewController see this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)

Comment: Worked, I was unaware of this change. Cheers!

Comment: @MattWinfrey - Have  a nice day bro, if my answer is working fine give the upvote

Comment: i wish i could, not enough rep yet. I'll get back to it when i can